# Error displaying info with an script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal, sh

I need to display certain info trough the terminal using a bash script.
The info i need to display is UID, PID, PPID, STATUS, CMD.
Okay, so i kind of did that already but i have certain issues with the identation and the printing.
I need to display it this way:

```
UID     PID     PPID     STATUS    CMD
root     1       0      Sleeping    /sbin/init
```

But with my code i get this:

```
UID     PID     PPID     STATUS    CMD
root     
1       0      (sleeping)    /sbin/init
```

This is my code actually:

```
echo "UID   PID  PPID    STATUS             CMD"

for i in /proc/*; do
getent passwd `cat $i/status|grep "^Uid"`| cut -d: -f1|head -1
cat $i/status|grep "^Pid"|awk '{printf "%-9s",$2}'
cat $i/status|grep "^PPid"|awk '{printf "%-9s",$2}'
cat $i/status|grep "^State"|awk '{printf"%-9s",$3}'
cat $i/cmdline|awk '{printf "      %-25s",$1}'
echo '\n'
done
```

With this code i also get a lot of "not a directory" errors.
I'm new at this so i need tons of help :( 
note: i can't use ps command

Comment: Check `man ps`...

Comment: as a restriction i can't use -ps

Comment: @RodrigoAlejandroMuozInostro And why such odd requirement?

Comment: because to i need create a ps command, with my code

Comment: So, you should learn C programming language

Comment: @RodrigoAlejandroMuozInostro Really? Are you kidding me? Well, good luck then!.

Answer (score 2):

The command ps (check man ps) could do all that all by itself:

```
$ ps -eo user,pid,ppid,state,cmd  | head -n 10
```

Answer (score 1):

The only problem is that `head` outputs a full line, but you want to suppress the newline. Do that by capturing the output and displaying it with `printf`.

The below also cleans up the more egregious uses of useless `cat` and `grep`, but could be simplified further.

```
echo "UID   PID  PPID    STATUS             CMD"

for i in /proc/*; do
  uid=$(getent passwd $(grep "^Uid" "$i/status") | cut -d: -f1 | head -1)
  printf '%-9s' "$uid"   # May need to adjust the formatting
  awk '/^Pid/ {printf "%-9s",$2}' "$i/status"
  awk '/^PPid/ {printf "%-9s",$2}' "$i/status"
  awk '/^State/ {printf"%-9s",$3}' "$i/status"
  awk '{printf "      %-25s\n",$1}' "$i/cmdline"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play with shell, first read docs :

- FAQ http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ
- Guide: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide
- Ref: http://gnu.org/s/bash/manual

Then to display what you need without any mess :

```
ps -c -o 'uid pid ppid status ucmd'
```

Comment: as a restriction i can't use ps